# Styling child components with css modules with React Select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Basically, I have this:

```js
import Select, { components } from 'react-select';
import classnames from 'classnames/bind';
const cx = classnames.bind(styles);
```

```js
<Select
className={cx('selectthis')}
classNamePrefix={cx('one')}
options={options}
></Select>
```

The container works perfect. But how would I use my classes with the prefix correctly, I don't want to override every single component and add my own classes. Also I don't want to use the style prop.

How do I configure this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a way to make this work? In this code sandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-mountain-wip00) it works, but not on my local machine.